# How to specify a text file in the command line

Tags: java, command-line

I am trying to create a program that reads from a text file. I use `cmd` and type in `javac fileName.java` to compile, then `java -cp . fileName` to run it. However, I want to run the program by writing `java fileName textInput.txt`. I have already created the program; but I have to specify the name of the text file in the code.

I was told that `args[0]` should be the name of the text file, but I am not sure how to implement this.

I have not posted my code, but tell me if I need to.

Comment: For more complex command line arguments you can use Commons CLI: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli//

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have your class as below

```
public class YourClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = args[0]; // would contain "textInput.txt"
        // work with fileName
    }
}
```

run your program as `java YourClass textInput.txt`.

The String array `args` contains any arguments you pass when you run the `java` command. It can be anything, not restricted to file names. As Bailey S puts it, these arguments are tokenized based on the tokenization of your shell. The index starts at 0.

```
       java YourClass arg1 arg2 arg3
                       ^    ^    ^
index:                 0    1    2
```

Comment: It is an array of the command line arguments tokenized on white-space.  Similar to `string.split("\s")`;

Comment: Thank you! I've modified my code and it works as I want it to now.

Comment: The tokenization is done by your shell (bash, Windows cmd shell, etc.), so it isn't just on whitespace. For instance, `java YourClass "Hello, World"` would typically give you just one argument, not two.

Answer (score 3):

```
String filePath = args[0];
// Do whatever with the file path
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class fileName {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       String filePath = args[0];
       //but check if args[0] exist.

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The main method of any Java program receive an array of `String` values which are the arguments passed via the command line:

```
java javaClass.class arg0 arg1 arg2
```

And here is how you catch from the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(args[0]); // prints arg0
    System.out.println(args[1]); // prints arg1
    System.out.println(args[2]); // prints arg2
}
```

It is better to check the number of arguments passed before using them:

```
if(args.length < 0) System.out.println("No arguments are passed!");
```